# Visual Studio 2017 "error" prevents editing of form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a weird one here. I have a Windows Forms app. I have the following line that I inserted manually in the Form Designer

```
this.btn_ab_resetAll.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { btn_ab_accStatus_Click(sender, EventArgs, "running"); };
```

But when I try to edit the Form Design in VS, I get the following error.

> The designer cannot process the code at line 577:
>   this.btn_ab_pauseAll.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => {
>   btn_ab_accStatus_Click(sender, EventArgs, "pause"); }; The code within
>   the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and
>   should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try
>   opening the designer again.

Which of course, if I click Ignore and Continue, then gives me a blank form in the Form Design window and I can no longer edit it.

BUT - The app shows no errors in the Error List pane. And it compiles and functions as expected.

However, this is no good to me if I can't edit the form anymore. Any ideas as to why VS is doing this?

Comment: If you need to add a new event handler such as this, don't add it into the designer file, add it into your form class code just after the `InitializeComponent()` call.  The error is because Visual Studio designer simply doesn't understand the lambda function syntax.

Comment: @Trevor can you please put this as an answer so I can accept it. You posted this before the other guy below did and also included a good explanation of why. And thanks for this. Tested and works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to add a new event handler such as this, don't add it into the designer file, add it into your form class code just after the `InitializeComponent()` call.

The error is because the Visual Studio designer tool simply doesn't understand the lambda function syntax you've used for the event handler, so is unable to start the designer as cannot parse the file.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the designer partial class, add your code in the constructor after the "InitializeComponent()" call.